# Program, that chooses the best out of 10

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to make a program in python that chooses cars from an array, that is filled with the mass of 10 cars. The idea is that it fills a barge, that can hold ~8 tonnes most effectively and minimum space is left unfilled. My idea is, that it makes variations of the masses and chooses one, that is closest to the max weight. But since I'm new to algorithms, I don't have a clue how to do it

Comment: Surely the class that this is homework for (right?) gave you some ideas.

Comment: Sounds like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: is weight your only consideration, or should the dimensions of the cars also be taken into account?

Comment: Only weight at this time

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the typical example for greedy algorithms - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem for a description and strategy for resolution.

Comment: This is clearly bin-packing algorithm and is not knapsack or tsp. I can't believe the other poster here. I'm so sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A problem like you have here is similar to the classic traveling salesman problem, which asks for the most efficient way for a salesman to visit a list of cities. The difference is that it is conceivable that you might not need every car to fill the barge, whereas the salesman must visit every city. But the problem is similar. The brute-force way to solve the problem is to investigate every possible combination of cars, from 1 car to all 10. We will assume that it is valid to have any number of each car (i.e. if car 2 is a Ford Focus, you could have three Ford Foci).  This is easy to change if the car list is an exact list of specific cars, however, and you can use only 1 of each.

Now, this quickly begins to consume a lot of time.  As the number of cars goes up, the number of possible combinations of cars goes up geometrically, which means that with a number smaller than you expect, it will take longer to run the program then there is time left in your life.  10 should be manageable, though (it turns out to be a little more than 700,000 combinations, or 1024 if you can only have one of each item).

The first thing is to define the weight of each car and the maximum weight the barge can carry.

```
weights = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2]
capacity = 8
```

Now we need some way to find each possible combination.  Python's `itertools` module has a function that will give us every combination of a given length, but we want all lengths. So we will write one loop that goes from 1 to 10 and calls `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` for each length. We can then find out the total weight of each combination, and if it is higher than any weight we have already found, yet still within capacity, we will remember it as the best we have found so far.

The only real trick here is that we don't want combinations of the weights -- we want combinations of the indexes of the weights, because at the end we want to know which cars to put on the barge, not their weights.  So `combinations_with_replacements(range(10), ...)` rather than `combinations_with_replacements(weights, ...)`. Inside the loop you will want to get the weight of each car in the combination with `weights[i]` to sum it up.

I originally had code here, but took it out since this is homework.  :-)  (It wasn't originally tagged as such, but I should have known -- I blame the time change.)

If you wanted to allow only one of each car, you'd use `itertools.combinations` instead of `combinations_with_replacement`.

A shortcut is possible since you mention elsewhere that cars weigh from 1-2 tonnes.  This means that you *know* you will need at least 4 of them (4 * 2 = 8), so you can skip all the combinations of 1-3 cars.  However, this wouldn't generalize well if the prof changed the parameters on you.

Comment: That's not true all posibilites of 10 cars is only 45 and not factorial(10!) and it's not like the tsp-problem but maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: @epitaph: each car is either included or excluded - so the total number of combinations is 2**10 = 1024. In general, for N objects, it will be 2**N - every extra object doubles the workload and more-than-doubles the runtime. N=270 gives you more combinations than there are atoms in the universe.

Comment: Yes, my assumption was that you could have any number of each car. The number of combinations in this case are much higher than the case where you can have only 1 of each car. The latter is what you actually have. (It is higher than 45 though.  :-)

Comment: If you have a graph with 10 cars each onnected to each other then the sum of all possible pairs is 45 ((n^2-n)/2)) and 45 is the sum of all combinations. What did I forgot?

Comment: Knapsack-problem has 2 variable (cost and weight). OP's problem is only weight so this can't be a knapsack-problem!

Comment: Yeah, good point. I failed to actually look that up and misremembered the details. I have edited. However I'm not sure I'm deserving of two downvotes for the sin.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a 1D bin-packing problem. It's a NP problem and there isn't an optimal solution. However there is a way to solve this with greedy algorithm. Most likely you want to try my bin-packing solver at phpclasses.org (bin-packing).

If I have a graph unweigthed and undirected and each node is connected which each node then I have (n^2-n)/2 pairs of node and overall n^2-n possibilities/combinations:

```
1,2,3,4,5,...,64
2,1,X,X,X,...,X
3,X,1,X,X,...,X
4,X,X,1,X,...,X
5,X,X,X,1,...,X
.,X,X,X,X,1,.,X
.,X,X,X,X,X,1,X
64,X,X,X,X,X,X,1
```

Isn't this the same with 10 cars? (45 pairs of cars and 90 combinations/possibilites). Did I forgot something? Where is the error?

Comment: How isn't there an optimal solution? I only have 10 numbers and after taking variations from them, there will be atleast 1, that is closest to the 8 tonnes. Cars weigh from 1 - 2 tonnes

Comment: You need to simplify the problem. If you forget about the 10 numbers then you are left alone with 8 tonnes and then it become a difficult problem because you don't know which combination cars you have to take to minimize the tonnes.

Comment: We were told that there will be only 10 cars maximum all the time.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about then it is a 1D-bin-packing problem its just a trap. Just forget about the cars!

Comment: I don't see how this will ever find solutions with more than two cars.

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this exercise with dynamic programming. You should be able to get the optimal solution in O(m*n) operations (n beeing the number of cars, m beeing the total mass).
That will only work however if the masses are all integers.

In general you have a binary linear programming problem. Those are very hard in general (NP-complete).

However, both ways lead to algorithms which I wouldn't consider to be beginners material. You might be better of with trial and error (as you suggested) or simply try every possible combination.

Comment: How to try every possible combination in python whilst giving it a limit of 8 tonnes?

Comment: Well, generate every possible combination of cars, sum their weight, check if its below 8 and if so by how much. Then simply memorize the best solution found. With 10 cars, a solution candidate could be a boolean array with 10 elements, each indicating if a particular car is used. You'll need to generate all possible boolean arrays of this kind (there will be 2^10=1024).

Comment: That's not true all possibilities of 10 cars is only 45 which this math (n^2-n)/2.

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't it possible to choose more than 2 cars of the ten? You argue with a graph, but I don't see how the problem is modelled in a graph. I'm pretty sure its 2^n.